# Android Sent Message Using Dual Sim

Tags: android

Some of the android phones support dual sim. I am trying to display the count of sms sent by the user from a particular number/sim. I can do the same if the mobile supports only one sim. I am facing problem with dual sim. Can anybody help me in this doing it programatically. Thanks in advance.